Identifying the cause of a refrigerator short
my fridge has been tripping the GFCI breaker 2-3 times a day for the last 4 days.
I've tried to isolate the problem to a few parts, but without luck:

I plugged the fridge in to a different circuit (also with GFCI), but it still trips it
I turned off the ice maker, but it still trips it

Curious if anyone has better techniques for isolating the part that is causing the issue? For instance, if I set up an audio recording device, maybe I'd hear a certain sound (e.g.,  the condenser activating) before the power shuts off.
I recognize that once I identify, it probably won't be DIY any more, but I'm posting here because I think the identification part can be DIY.
Thanks.
UPDATE 1: Thanks for everyone's ideas. 2 new pieces of info. This began when I changed the water filter, in the hopes of getting the ice maker to work better. I also did a full defrost just before this happened.
I'm in the middle of trying @JACK's ideas, to 1) fully unplug the ice maker and 2) turn off the water supply.

Can you get your paws on a "megger"/insulation resistance tester?

GFCI's trip on very minor shorts.  A bit of damaged insulation on a wire, a little bit moisture can do it.  Might check on wires that go though holes in metal without protection.  With the fridge unplugged first.

Try unplugging the icemaker, might have to remove it.  turning it off doesn't remove voltage from the freezer and current could be leaking from the freezer  outlet.  Try plugging the refrig into a non GFCI outlet.

Even better than unplugging the ice maker is to turn off the water supply to the refrigerator and drain as much water as you can out. There are basically two different possibilities here - one is related to water for the ice maker causing a moisture-based ground fault. The other is issues with the rest of the refrigerator - I don't quite understand the physics of it, but apparently the other parts can over time degrade to the point where they can cause a detectable ground fault.  How old is the refrigerator? Model #?

@JACK Thanks. Trying that right now. Will try the water supply idea next.
It's a Frigidaire (FDBG2250SSO) and about 8 or 9 years old.

Some other 'not insulated (enough) anymore' ideas — a screw with a fiber or plastic washer, maybe over-torqued at the factory, an open connector that caught a stray drop or splash from the defrost. I would try disconnecting more things. Or if you can leave it off for a while, put a fan/heat to dry things out in the mechanicals. I second the non-GFCI idea, too. Running it a few hours may freeze the damp causing your problem.

It is likely not a "short circuit". GFCI's trip easily due to inductive voltage spikes, likely when a motor turns on or off. This is a frequent issue and has been addressed before. Put this query into Brave or Google search engines: "gfci refrigerator site:diy.stackexchange.com/"
